# Issue in starting service

Tags: installation, installshield

all
I work with InstallScript in InstallShield 2011
I am facing problem while starting service .

I used ServiceAddService to add the new service to the service list.Service was successfully added to the list. but while starting this service gives the error "Service is not responding to the control function". **ServiceStartservice** has been used to start the service.

I have tried  also create my own functon using **LaunchApplication** to avoid the problem with:
"Windows auto checks whether a SERVICE which is run got a control function (if so it is a service).. if not it will run it for 10/15 seconds and sees that it doesn't responds with the special control services terminate it..."(I found this information in one of forums). But also get the error "Service is not responding to the control function".

I also tried start the service in cmd by typing **net start ServiceName**
And when I try to start it from services list I get this one: Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Searching for problem I created that: In imported to project XML file , after installation compleated, in 2 tags appears repetitions of already existing line in attributes that I'm not  modifing.

where it could go wrong? 
can you please help me with this issue?
could the XML wrong modyfing to be a reason for such error?

Thanks, Sigal

Comment: Wall Of Text:: please put some line breaks in your description.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like an application problem that could be contributed by the installer.   Have you debugged / profiled the service?   Is it missing any dependencies?  DLL's, COM registration,  data/log directories, permissions and so on.    Once you identify "why" it's failing you can identify if the fix is in the service code or the installer code.

Comment: I checked that service installation succeeded .Also I have previous installation version(not using installshield)installing using the same ServiceName.exe and running the service without the problem. XML modified successfully in required places. And I have also log file where I can see if function succeeded or failed. 
The problem appear in "net start". Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion  
Like I understand from the error :  service doesn't reach its running state before function returning. But I can't understand why

Comment: The service might have been created but you can't say it's successful until you understand why the service won't start and determine the root cause.   Do you have any logging in your service?  Can you attach a debugger to it?